# static HTML landing pages with Create React App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, create-react-app

Hi I have a static html landing page which has its own css, static assets, and is linked to a couple other static pages. So the whole mini project has its own index.html, about-us.html, contact.html etc. In addition, I also have built a react app through CRA where I have this really cool dashboard, now I want to combine the two where the entry point to my website is the landing page and then when you go to the /dashboard path that is my react application How can I achieve this?

So the project structure for my static landing page project looks like so:

```
/homepage
--index.html
--contact.html
--about-us.html
--/static
----css files, imgs, ect
```

My React Project uses react router so I have a fully functioning React project at the path /dashboard

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login/Login";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import SignupPage from "./components/Signup/SignupPage";

const App = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: You should add in the question what you have tried so far. But if the static landing page is going to be displayed first, you should use [React Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) and create routes for `/dashboard` in your React App

Comment: I am already using React Router to serve all my react stuff like /dashboard but I'm not sure how I am supposed to serve the index.html

Comment: If you are going to deploy that app you use some backend server to display the static files like [Express](https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3)

Comment: Oooo so is there no way to combine this with React?

Comment: You could use Apache to serve the static HTML files, and a separate Express server to serve your React app. But then you would have to use different ports for each of them. I would recommend you to add your static files in your SPA to serve them all but separated routes, like `/dashboard` for your app, and `/` for your landing page.

Comment: I see... So I have to use a server to route to the different files as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After you run `yarn build` your create react app will have a folder called `build` with several files in it. The files that interest you will be `index.html` and everything under the `static` folder.

The index.html file can be copied to anywhere in your web server. It can be renamed without an issue. The `static` folder needs to be  at the root directory for your webpage - `index.html` references all the files as being in `/static`.

The names and file structure can be changed, but you would have to eject your CRA project and edit the scripts yourself.

Comment: so I would have to manually rewrite the CRA scripts to enable the sort of functionality I'm seeking?

Comment: There's no shame in having a copy-paste step in your deployment, and it's easy to implement automation for it. That said, you're at the point where you may have graduated from CRA to owning your own webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try **adding settings on your server so that the /dashboard route points to your react app.**
Example in NGINX you can add configuration

```
location ^~ /dashboard {
alias <yourprojectfolder>/build;
try_files $uri $uri/ /dashboard /index.html;
}
```

You will probably need to add the "basename" attribute to the route settings of your react application:

```
<Router basename="/dashboard ">
```

---

---

If that doesn't work, **rewrite each of your html pages as a view in React**.
I understand that you don't have a lot of javascript and you won't have too many problems.

**Additionally**

you can use the "styled-component" module to wrap your views in case your page is visually defaced by leaking css to other components.